# normal flow of html..behaves weird.. Is it right to code positioning in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From a very long time I am thinking of asking this. But was not sure if I should ask this question. I have been very lost seeing the behaviour of html elements with normal flow. It is sometimes very difficult to control them. Specially when I am using server side coding as well to create dynamic content. Sometimes, I take more time to understand what going on with these elements that I take to code server side or javascript. For me its very difficult to understand how a change will affect some other element.

So, I have thought of using absolute and relative positioning for elements and placing them based upon calculation of innerWidth and innerHeight of the window which will also make it responsive. I feel I wil have more control like that.

On window resize I can again position the element to make it dynamic with window resize. 
Just like the code below,

```
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById("gamectrl").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("gamectrl").style.top = document.getElementById("rtctrls").offsetTop + 10 + "px";
document.getElementById("gamectrl").style.left = document.getElementById("rtctrls").offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
}

window.onresize = function()
{
    document.getElementById("gamectrl").style.top = document.getElementById("rtctrls").offsetTop + 10 + "px";
    document.getElementById("gamectrl").style.left = document.getElementById("rtctrls").offsetLeft + 10 + "px"; 
}
```

Do you think it is the right way to position html elements? I am very comfortable with this. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Please share if you have any experience on this. I am very confused about which approach to use. I dont understand the normal flow of html elements properly as I could not find any good resources which discuss them in depth. So, if you know any good resource to learn about normal document flow(in-depth) then do share as well.

Comment: Here is [a resource about positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme). The "normal flow" is `position:static`.

Comment: Your requirement about positioning and responsive web is slightly confusing. Is it possible to create a fiddle with your requirement that we can edit? Positioning elements with offsetTop and offsetLeft is not really a good idea. With box modelling, (though a bit difficult to understand for beginners) you can control positioning accurately.

Comment: Absolute positioning for elements which are part of a document's flow should be very much avoided. One reason is that if users use text zoom they can break your brittle layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use javascript to just reposition an element giving the example you've shown. In your example I would stick to using CSS. If you're concerned about the browser/device resizing then you need to look into using `@media` queries. If you need to have your elements a certain distance away from the edge of the window or another element you can set the element's `margin` with percentage values (ex. `margin-top: 10%;`).  Below are some references to positioning with CSS as well as `@media` queries.

1. Media Queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ Media
2. Queries: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp CSS
3. Positioning: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101 CSS
4. Positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp